# Hosting MVC Core Application without publishing

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

We started to work in a MVC core application. I have seen many web sites about hosting Core applications after publishing. Can we host a MVC core web app without publishing, that is copy all files from local to server machine using ftp as we do in asp.net project? Since it is in development stage there is lot of changes in every day and it is difficult to upload these changes after publishing.

Comment: Have you tried it? Create a project. Build it. Copy to local IIS. Configure Site and hit it? It's a matter of minutes.

Comment: i have tried that ,but i want to know if it is possible to do without publishing.I am familiar with uploading files which has changes ,just want to stick with it

Comment: That makes no sense. If you have tried it, you should know if it is possible. If you encountered problems, specify them

Comment: i have tried after publishing and it is success . but without publishing it is not working

Comment: "...  it is not working" is not working as a question. Post errors, expected/actual etc.

Comment: But look for "XCopy Deployment", it is a known and supported pratice.